# Generic implementation of median #2: Follow up

Tags: c++, median, constrained-templates

Follow on from this codereview:

[generic implementation of median](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/273817/generic-implementation-of-median/273835)

As before the `vector2` class is just for illustrative purposes and not the focus.

I have incorporated all the excellent feedback from G.Sliepen from previous codereview linked above:

- 2 versions `median()` and `median_in_place()`. The former makes a copy.
- constrain inputs with concepts
- simpler syntax for default input parameters
- provides overloads which accept a range
- uses a projection parameter - no more `extract`
- uses `std::invoke` to support member functions
- uses `std::midpoint` for a safer average

Two main questions:

1. Use of concepts: It is "best/preferable" to constrain each of the wrappers as shown below, ie `median()` wraps `median_in_place()` and concepts are used at both levels. This is somewhat repetitive, but has subtle differences. Or would it be better, to use Duck typing for the wrappers and only put concept constraints on the main, inner function. Discuss.
2. Would it be helpful to specify the return types using trailing return syntax?  If so, I was unable to find a syntax which works. I suspect, I failed because I needed one or more of `std::remove_cv` or `std::remove_const` or `std::decay`. How to do that? Or not worth it?  Discuss.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>
#include <ostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

template <typename T>
class vector2 {
public:
  T x{};
  T y{};

  constexpr vector2(T x_, T y_) : x(x_), y(y_) {}

  constexpr vector2() = default;

  [[nodiscard]] T       mag() const { return std::hypot(x, y); }
  [[nodiscard]] vector2 norm() const { return *this / this->mag(); }
  [[nodiscard]] double  dot(const vector2& rhs) const { return x * rhs.x + y * rhs.y; }

  // clang-format off
  vector2& operator+=(const vector2& obj) { x += obj.x; y += obj.y; return *this; }
  vector2& operator-=(const vector2& obj) { x -= obj.x; y -= obj.y; return *this; }
  vector2& operator*=(const double& scale) { x *= scale; y *= scale; return *this; }
  vector2& operator/=(const double& scale) { x /= scale; y /= scale; return *this; }
  // clang-format on

  friend vector2 operator+(vector2 lhs, const vector2& rhs) { return lhs += rhs; }
  friend vector2 operator-(vector2 lhs, const vector2& rhs) { return lhs -= rhs; }
  friend vector2 operator*(vector2 lhs, const double& scale) { return lhs *= scale; }
  friend vector2 operator*(const double& scale, vector2 rhs) { return rhs *= scale; }
  friend vector2 operator/(vector2 lhs, const double& scale) { return lhs /= scale; }

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const vector2& v) {
    return os << '[' << v.x << ", " << v.y << ']';
  }
};

using vec2  = vector2<double>;
using vec2I = vector2<int>;

template <typename RandomAccessIter, typename Comp = std::ranges::less,
          typename Proj = std::identity>
requires std::random_access_iterator <RandomAccessIter> && std::sortable<RandomAccessIter, Comp, Proj>
auto median_in_place(RandomAccessIter first, RandomAccessIter last, const Comp& comp = {},
                     const Proj& proj = {}) {

  auto size = std::distance(first, last);
  if (size == 0) throw std::domain_error("Can't find median of an empty range.");

  auto middle = first + (size / 2);

  std::ranges::nth_element(first, middle, last, comp, proj);

  if (size % 2 == 1) return std::invoke(proj, *middle);

  auto below_middle = std::ranges::max_element(first, middle, comp, proj);

  return std::midpoint(std::invoke(proj, *middle), std::invoke(proj, *below_middle));
}

template <typename RandomAcccessRange, typename Comp = std::less<>, typename Proj = std::identity>
requires std::ranges::random_access_range<RandomAcccessRange> &&
    std::sortable<typename RandomAcccessRange::iterator, Comp, Proj>
auto median_in_place(RandomAcccessRange& range, const Comp& comp = {}, const Proj& proj = {}) {
  return median_in_place(range.begin(), range.end(), comp, proj);
}

template <typename InputIter, typename Comp = std::ranges::less, typename Proj = std::identity>
requires std::input_iterator<InputIter> &&
    std::sortable<typename std::vector<std::iter_value_t<InputIter>>::iterator, Comp, Proj>
auto median(InputIter first, InputIter last, const Comp& comp = {}, const Proj& proj = {}) {
  std::vector<std::iter_value_t<InputIter>> input_copy(first, last); // always make a copy
  return median_in_place(input_copy.begin(), input_copy.end(), comp, proj);
}

template <typename InputRange, typename Comp = std::less<>, typename Proj = std::identity>
requires std::ranges::input_range<InputRange> &&
    std::sortable<typename std::vector<std::ranges::range_value_t<InputRange>>::iterator, Comp,
                  Proj>
auto median(const InputRange& range, const Comp& comp = {}, const Proj& proj = {}) {
  return median(range.begin(), range.end(), comp, proj);
}

template <typename T>
void print(const std::vector<T>& v) {
  std::cout << "[";
  char delim[2]{}; // NOLINT char[] OK here
  for (const auto& e: v) {
    std::cout << static_cast<char*>(delim) << e;
    delim[0] = ',';
  }
  std::cout << "]\n";
}

template <typename T>
void print(const std::list<T>& v) {
  std::cout << "[";
  char delim[2]{}; // NOLINT char[] OK here
  for (const auto& e: v) {
    std::cout << static_cast<char*>(delim) << e;
    delim[0] = ',';
  }
  std::cout << "]\n";
}

int main() {
  {
    const std::vector<int> ints{9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
    print(ints);
    std::cout << "median(ints) = " << median(ints) << "\n";
    print(ints);
  }
  {
    std::vector<int> ints{9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
    print(ints);
    std::cout << "median_in_place(ints) = " << median_in_place(ints) << "\n";
    print(ints);
  }
  {
    const std::list<vec2> vec2s{{9, 8}, {7, 6}, {5, 4}, {3, 2}};
    print(vec2s);
    std::cout << "median(mag(vec2)) = " << median(vec2s, {}, &vec2::mag) << "\n";
    print(vec2s);
  }
  {
    std::vector<vec2> vec2s{{9, 8}, {7, 6}, {5, 4}, {3, 2}};
    print(vec2s);
    std::cout << "median_in_place(mag(vec2)) using lambda = "
              << median_in_place(vec2s, {}, [](const auto& v) { return v.mag(); }) << "\n";
    print(vec2s);
  }
  {
    std::vector<vec2> vec2s{{9, 8}, {7, 6}, {5, 4}, {3, 2}};
    print(vec2s);
    std::cout << "median_in_place(mag(vec2) using iters) = "
              << median_in_place(vec2s.begin(), vec2s.end(), {},
                                 [](const auto& v) { return v.mag(); })
              << "\n";
    print(vec2s);
  }
}
```

Comment: Completely coincidentally, I was playing with a median implementation today, with slightly different emphasis.  I don't use a separate projection function (but can get the same effect with a custom `midpoint()`).  If you're interested, my review request is _[Find median of values without copying](/q/274030/75307)_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Be as generic as possible

Your `median()` and `median_in_place()` functions don't work on all things that are ranges, because you didn't use generic functions/types everywhere. Consider for example trying to get the median of a plain array:

```
double values[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
std::cout << median(values) << '\n';
```

This will fail because you are using `range.begin()` and `range.end()` instead of `std::ranges::begin(range)` and `std::ranges::end(range)`. Fixing that, there still is an issue if you use `median_in_place()`, since you constrained it to:

```
std::sortable<typename RandomAcccessRange::iterator, Comp, Proj>
```

This should be:

```
std::sortable<std::ranges::iterator_t<RandomAcccessRange>, Comp, Proj>
```

There's also a problem with your `print()` function. Instead of making it a template on the value type, and have explicit overloads for the different containers, make it a template on the container type (or rather, range) instead:

```
template <std::ranges::input_range T>
void print(const T& v) {
  std::cout << "[";
  const char *delim = "";
  for (const auto& e: v) {
    std::cout << delim << e;
    delim = ", ";
  }
  std::cout << "]\n";
}
```

Now you can even print a plain array.
And as Toby Speight did in his answer, even avoid it always printing to `std::cout`, and have it take a `std::ostream` reference parameter.

## Answers to your questions

> 1. Use of concepts: It is "best/preferable" to constrain each of the wrappers as shown below, ie `median()` wraps `median_in_place()` and concepts are used at both levels. This is somewhat repetitive, but has subtle differences. Or would it be better, to use Duck typing for the wrappers and only put concept constraints on the main, inner function.

For the most concise error messages, it's best to add concepts to all public functions.

> 2. Would it be helpful to specify the return types using trailing return syntax? If so, I was unable to find a syntax which works. I suspect, I failed because I needed one or more of `std::remove_cv` or `std::remove_const` or `std::decay`. How to do that? Or not worth it?

I personally don't see the need to specify a return type at all. Just let it be automatically deduced. If you do want it though, then it probably should be this:

```
template <...>
requires ...
auto median_in_place(RandomAccessIter first, RandomAccessIter last,
                     const Comp& comp = {}, const Proj& proj = {})
-> std::decay_t<std::invoke_result_t<Proj, std::iter_value_t<RandomAccessIter>>>
{
    ...
}
```

The `std::iter_value_t` is required to get the value type of the range, then you need to get the result type after `Proj` is applied, but since that might be a reference (especially if it's [`std::identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/identity)), you also need to use `std::decay_t` on that.

Comment: The first point applied to my recent question, and I've now fixed it, so thank you for educating more than just the asker!

Comment: Thanks for the point on c-arrays. Not "sloppy",  I am simply not yet used to writing generic code in a world with ranges. The print function was purely ad hoc, not serious code. I hate writing these container printers, and in my code proper, I always use `std::format`  which solves this properly. But it is not yet supported by most compilers so I don't use it on CR. Hence the ad-hoc `print()`. I also find the clobbering of the `const char* ptr` "hacky". The whole (two) function(s) shouldn't exist.  Thanks for answers to questions, particularly the return type.

Comment: Please don't take criticism personal. I mentioned sloppy because you did use things like `std::iter_value_t<InputIter>` correctly in some places, instead of `InputIter::value_type`. Printing containers can be done in a one-liner using `std::ranges::copy(range, std::ostream_iterator<type>(std::cout, ","))` for example, or indeed use the excellent `std::format()`. I don't think changing a mutable pointer to point to something else is hacky. You could've used a `std::string` instead to avoid this altogether.

Comment: All of the print options (other than std::format) are bad. They are either verbose and/or don't integrate well. Passing `std::ostream` as second param doesn't solve anything, really, because we still can't use `operator<<` because that is in `std::`. This was just a glaring hole, for doing sth trivial, with many "clever yet inadequate solutions", in c++ for > 20yrs. `std::format` finally solves it.

Comment: Changing the `const char* ptr` is no better than changing the stack based `char[]`... they are both bad, because they are "bending over backwards" to do something which is unbelievably awkward to solve, because it should have been solved with `std::vector::operator<<` 20 yrs ago.

Comment: There is a difference: changing the `const char* ptr` to point to another string literal is very safe, modifying an array on the stack less so because you need to ensure that array is large enough and properly NUL-terminated. A `std::vector::operator<<` would be very bad: how should it format the contents of the vector? Is `","` a proper separator? But what if it's a vector of strings and the strings contain commas? Should it quote the string, and if so escape quote characters? Should it add a newline? It quickly gets complicated and much less generic.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `std::midpoint()`, it might be better to allow types to have their own `midpoint()` function (in their namespace), and only fall back on `std::midpoint()` if that's not found:

```
using std::midpoint;
return midpoint(std::invoke(proj, *middle),
                std::invoke(proj, *below_middle));
```

We have `median_in_place()` that accepts a range, but then miss our chance to use it.

```
return median_in_place(input_copy, comp, proj);
```

We can use short form of constrained templates:

```
template <std::random_access_iterator RandomAccessIter,
          typename Comp = std::ranges::less,
          typename Proj = std::identity>
requires std::sortable<RandomAccessIter, Comp, Proj>
```

We might want a constraint that `RandomAccessIter::value_type` is copyable or movable as appropriate in the functions, too.

---

The tests are weak, because the inputs are always sorted or reverse-sorted.  Some extra tests with the median at beginning or end would give extra confidence that `nth_element()` was actually being called!

We're missing tests that use a provided comparator.  Perhaps we could compare `vector2` objects by their *x* coordinate?

We don't need a separate `print()` for each container type.  And we can avoid the `static_cast` by reassigning a pointer:

```
void print(std::ranges::input_range auto const& v,
           std::ostream& os = std::cout)
{
    os << "[";
    const char* delim = "";
    for (const auto& e: v) {
        os << delim << e;
        delim = ",";
    }
    os << "]\n";
}
```

---

The `vector2` implementation should accept `double` arguments by value.  Passing as `double const&` gives no benefit.

Comment: Interesting point on midpoint... similar to what happens with `std::swap`. I like that. Your pedantically worded comments on the "tests" are not really appreciated. This is clearly not a test suite, but merely a demo of SOME of the features. The combinatorial explosion of a proper test suite would have meant that they they would have taken up 90% of the code. You didn't answer the questions..

Comment: Yes, proper unit tests would certainly be helpful - I probably should have suggested that.

Comment: CR is not a forum to submit production quality libraries with full test suites,  benchmarks, continuous integration testing on multiple platforms etc. That takes a proper repository not a couple of markup boxes. Which is why CR is so limited in the code it can realistically hope to evaluate. I had this debate last year and stopped answering questions as a result. It's "Stack Overflow... with slightly longer, and hopefully slightly better thought through, questions". It can't be more, due to the format.

Comment: @OliverSchönrock I agree that including long test suites in the question is probably not helpful if you just want to focus on the actual code, but Toby's remark that your tests are weak is still valid criticism. Had you implemented more tests, you probably would've caught some of the issues we have found. Also, CR and StackOverflow are not just for the benefit of the OP, they are also for others who are just browsing questions and trying to learn from them, so any advice given that might not be useful for you might still be useful for others.

Comment: @G.Sliepen I disagree. Those comments were not valid or helpful. Your comment about c-arrays is helpful. And those are not TESTS. They are demo code, specifically for the purpose of posting on CR. All in one file.. demo in main without any test framework..  And the wording.. "Your tests are WEAK"... they are NOT tests. 

Sorry, in my eye he purely postured and didn't even bother to answer the actual questions. Personally I only posted this CR because you advised me to do so. There is barely any additional content here beyond the first one.

Comment: I just reviewed the code as posted.  If that's useful to you then that's good.  If there was stuff you didn't want reviewed, a suggestion for next time is to put that into a separate code block (and perhaps blockquote it) and be specific.  Personally, I like to have everything reviewed when I post, since it's all opportunity to learn and improve.  I actually found it quite hard to review this one with all the `vector2` stuff and the test program (sorry, "demo program") mixed in (sharing the includes, for example).